# CakePHP app is really slow after it is transfered for different host

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have similar problem as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937168/incredibly-slow-load-times-using-cakephp-on-godaddy-hosting/9470879#9470879

My cakephp app is too slow to be real...
Some details:

1. With debug as 2 it runs fine on my localhost with test database
2. With debug as 2 it is reaaally slow on my test host with test database
3. With debug as 0 it runs fine on my test host with test database

Debug Kit timer says almost the same time for each one of the three attempts.

I need debug = 2 on my test server... One difference is that in test server its inside the trunk folder that was checked out with and on my localhost its directly checked inside the project folder.

Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like a hosting issue if it is fine on your home machine, you want to establish what the differences are with the platforms.  Also, probably not a SO question, maybe http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue. In order to fault the server, try to do a simple select sql by selecting a number of records using php. Do not use cakePHP to do the above. If the load time is the same, the database configuration has some problems at the server side.

Comment: Thank you very much for being interested. Actually they have made something in the host that fully solved the problem. Will never know what was that. But I think if I had thought like that I could have a clue.